# Install matplotlib with Plone 4.3.3 via buildout

Tags: matplotlib, plone

How to install matplotlib with Plone 4.3.3 via buildout without using setuptools or pip?

I've installed numpy via buildout `eggs += numpy`.

When adding `matplotlib` to buildout I get the following message:

```
$ sudo -u plone_buildout /home/Plone-4.3.3/zeocluster/bin/buildout -c /home/Plone-4.3.3/zeocluster/develop.cfg
Uninstalling zopeskel.
Uninstalling test.
Uninstalling precompiler.
Uninstalling zopepy.
Uninstalling client2.
Uninstalling client1.
Updating _mr.developer.
Updating zeoserver.
Installing client1.
Getting distribution for 'matplotlib'.
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.4.0]
                python: yes [2.7.6 (default, Apr 28 2014, 19:51:17)  [GCC
                        4.4.5]]
              platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
                   six: yes [six was not found.]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                 pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1966, in main
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1953, in with_ei_usage
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1970, in <lambda>
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 360, in run
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 584, in easy_install
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 633, in install_item
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 827, in install_eggs
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1107, in build_and_install
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1093, in run_setup
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in run_setup
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 117, in run
  File "/home/Plone-4.3.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 69, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 154, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-lsJUIA/matplotlib-1.4.0/setupext.py", line 940, in check
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
An error occurred when trying to install matplotlib 1.4.0. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing client1.
  Getting distribution for 'matplotlib'.
Error: Couldn't install: matplotlib 1.4.0
```

Comment: This do not seems an error message. Maybe some more traceback will help.

Comment: I've updated the question with the whole message

Comment: The real error you must search for is `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`.
Googling for it you will find this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593512/cant-install-matplotlib-using-pip
Try it, and good luck